# Gutenberg Block - Post Featured Image Filter Hook

Tags: filters, hooks, block-editor, customization

I'm wanting to add some functionality to the featured image block in the Gutenberg editor. I've got pretty close:

[image]

The problem is, I'm unable to select an image, and posts that already had a featured image assigned are not loading the image in the block.

I think this must be due to the `original` block object's key not being set. I've tried a random value, the post id, the media post id, 'render', 'thumbnail', and 'post-thumbnail', but no dice. What is 'my-key' suppose to be set to? Why is the featured image not loading, and not able to be set and saved?

```
window.wp.hooks.addFilter( 
    'editor.PostFeaturedImage', 
    'myplugin/myhook', 
    function( original ) { 
        console.log (original);
        return function() { 
            return (
                window.wp.element.createElement( 
                    'div', 
                    { key: 'outer' + Math.random() }, 
                    [
                        'Prepend above',
                        _.extend( original( {} ), { key: 'my-key' } ),
                        'Append below' 
                    ]
                )
            );
        } 
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/editor/src/components/post-featured-image/README.md#setup):

> Prepend and append to the panel contents:
>
> ```
> var el = wp.element.createElement;
>
> function wrapPostFeaturedImage( OriginalComponent ) { 
>   return function( props ) {
>       return (
>           el(
>               wp.element.Fragment,
>               {}, 
>               'Prepend above',
>               el(
>                   OriginalComponent,
>                   props
>               ),
>               'Append below'
>           )
>       );
>   } 
> } 
>
> wp.hooks.addFilter( 
>   'editor.PostFeaturedImage', 
>   'my-plugin/wrap-post-featured-image', 
>   wrapPostFeaturedImage
> );
> ```

So did you intentionally not using `wp.element.Fragment`?

You may also want to check the example here:

- [Gutenberg: Extending Featured Image Component](https://digitalapps.co/gutenberg-extending-featured-image-component/)

Comment: I was following a much less informative guide. This did the trick. Thank you thank you, thank you.